# Generating resources with frontend-maven-plugin throws NoSuchFileException for semver when the file does exist

Tags: java, maven, npm, semantic-versioning

I am using the `frontend-maven-plugin` to run `npm` commands during the build process. The `npm` commands run fine, but the build fails when trying to copy resources:

```
[DEBUG] file semver has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resource 'semver'.
[DEBUG] copy /[...]/src/main/resources/emails/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/.bin/semver to /[...]/target/classes/emails/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/.bin/semver
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.066 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-17T11:33:04+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project [...]: /[...]/target/classes/emails/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/.bin/semver -> [Help 1]
[...]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /[...]/target/classes/emails/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/.bin/semver
```

However, the file does exist.

```
~/[...]/target/classes/emails/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/.bin $ ls -@l                                                                 
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 [...]  [...]  20 17 May 11:33 semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
```

What can I do to stop this happening, given that the plugin otherwise appears to be working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `/node_modules/` folder has nothing to deal with generated `/target/` folder, you can try to exclude it from resource processing in `pom.xml` ([more about resource tag in pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources)):

```
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/node_modules/**</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```